# Inject text file into a zip folder in Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jetty

We have requirement to inject text file inside a zip folder which is stored in S3.

We have application running on Jetty. when one of our end point gets called we need to inject a text file inside zip folder which is stored in S3 and share the s3 url(zip folder location) so that caller can download the zip.

Question:
Are there any api from which we can access s3 bucket zip folder from application which is hosted on jetty and inject text file inside zip folder of s3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do anything to the file while its on S3. So this leaves you with two options.

1. If the text file doesnt change, add the zip file upon upload. In this case the user can download directly from s3.
2. If you can't use option 1, you will need to download the file, inject your text file, and then pass the file to the end user. The user will not be able to down the file directly from s3, but instead they will get it from your application.

Comment: thanks!, But I thought with Amazon API's we can connect from EC2 to S3 and inject the file.

Comment: You can get objects from s3. But you can't modify them while on s3.